# Cloud Build "Google Cloud Platform was not authorised to list repositories"

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I want to deploy a private GitHub repository with Cloud Run on Google Cloud Plattform.
In GitHub, I properly installed Google Cloud Build Application by clicking "Authenticate" in Cloud Run.
But somehow, Google tells me "Currently not authenticated" even though I clicked it another time.
In Cloud Build I checked and it tells me "Google Cloud Platform was not authorised to list repositories".
What am I doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the feature working at all (can you setup a repo) or not? The "Currently not authenticated" label might show if there's something blocking OAuth process from Google authenticating to your Github account (like an extension, or cookie blocker).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It finally let me connect the repo to Cloud Build when I opened it in incognito tab. There might be a conflict with an add on or so..

Comment: Good tip, I had to do it in Incognito mode too.

Answer (score 6):

For other persons, I my case, I use mutiples account of google, and my account of GCP is a seccond, when i auth in github, the callback redirect to first account. For resolve, I log-out all account and log-in only in my gcp account.

:)

Comment: Thanks, in my case i did open an incognito mode and make it from there